# Can i customise my crispy form in template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I need to add after every label tag  which will be button to enable input, so can i somehow do that in template?
so  can i turn this

```
    <form method="POST" action="/guide_register/" class="guide_register col-md-4">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {%crispy form%}
    </form>
```

into something like this

```
<form action="/profile/"  method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-row">
                {{field.label_tag}}
                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                {{field}}

            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            <div class="form-row">
            <input type="submit" value="Підтвердити" class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="reset" class=" btn btn-secondary" value="Відмінити">
            </div>
        </form>
```

but with crispy

Comment: i can probably do that with js, but this is not very elegan way

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You will have to do it in `forms.py`. For example I have this form for a post.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('body', 'image')
```

Now for example I want to change the placeholer of the body input of this form, I can do it like this:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    body = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'placeholder':'Share something with the world!'
        })
    )

    class Meta():
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('body', 'image')
```

A widget is Django’s representation of an HTML input element. The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget.